# Show Infragistics RowEditTemplate in Visual Studio Designer View

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, infragistics

We are using Infragistics in a Windows Forms application.  I am trying to modify a RowEditTemplate on a  Form that has an UltraGrid that when clicked opens a RowEditTemplate.

I've tried setting the RowEditTemplate to visible, and that crashes the designer.  I haven't been able to find any helpful documentation.

How do you view the RowEditTemplate in the designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that you have an UltraGrid on the form with added band to it, in order to go through the UltraGridRowEditTemplate's wizard after its first step.

1. In design time from the Toolbox, drag and drop
   UltraGridRowEditTemplate on the form.
2. Then the UltraGridRowEditTemplate will start its wizard.
3. Once you finish wizard's steps, you will be allowed to customize the
   template.